# After upgrading to 22.04 screen stays at a black screen when logging in

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, thinkpad, login-screen

I'm using a Lenovo ThinkPad P15s. I recently upgraded Ubuntu to 22.04, but after rebooting I can't seem to log in to my account, and the screen stays blank. I performed a system restore and was able to log in, but after rebooting I encountered the same problem. I assume that this update may contain some bugs. Is there an easy way to fix this issue?

Comment: I was able to solve the issue with this guide:  https://www.stephenwagner.com/2019/05/05/ubuntu-linux-black-screen-frozen-system-after-upgrade-install/

Answer (score 0):

Walrus4786 was able to solve the issue with [this tutorial](https://www.stephenwagner.com/2019/05/05/ubuntu-linux-black-screen-frozen-system-after-upgrade-install/) as shown below.

---

After upgrading a computer from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04  or Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04, during boot the screen goes blank (turns black), all hard disk activity halts, and the system becomes frozen. This event can also occur on a fresh installation or when updates are installed.

This is due to a video mode issue that causes the system to halt or freeze.

#### Temporary fix

To get the system to boot:

1. After turning on your PC, hold the right Shift key to get to the GRUB bootloader if your computer uses a BIOS. If your computer uses EFI or UEFI, continuously tap the Esc key after turning on your  PC.
2. Once GRUB is open, press the “e” key to edit the first highlighted entry “Ubuntu”.
3. Move your cursor down to the line that starts with `linux`, and use the right arrow key to find the section with the words `ro quiet splash`.
4. Add `nomodeset` after these words.
5. Feel free to remove `quiet` and `splash` for more verbosity to troubleshoot the boot process.
6. Press either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.
7. The system should now boot.

#### Permanent fix

To permanently resolve the issue:

1. Once the system has booted using the temporary fix, log in.
2. Open a terminal window (Dash -> Terminal, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>).
3. Either `su` in to root, or use `sudo` to open your favorite text editor and edit the file `/etc/default/grub` (I use nano which can be installed by running `sudo apt install nano`):

   ```
   nano /etc/default/grub
   ```
4. Locate the line with the variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, and add `nomodeset` to the variables. Feel free to remove `splash` and `quiet` if you'd like text boot. Here's an example of my line after editing  (yours will look different):

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
   ```
5. Save the file and exit the text editor (Ctrl+X to quit, then press `y` and Enter to save).
6. At the bash prompt, execute the following command to regenerate the grub.conf file on the `/boot` partition from your new default file:

   ```
   update-grub
   ```
7. Restart your system. It should now boot!